# Inheritance in Variable Value - Python

Tags: python, variables, inheritance

Well, I'm having trouble in a specific part of my code. It uses kivy, however I'm pretty sure there is a python solution. Here is the thing: I'll have a button, when pressed will take me to another screen, when it's pressed, calls method **vai**, that changes, or should change the string variable value that was created in **init** method. Afterwards, when another screen shows up, its button receives that CHANGED variable at text parameter. But the real issue is that by the time second screen appears, the button text does not change, remaining the value I set up on **init** once, not the changed value on **vai** method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Principal(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM()

class SM(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SM, self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(Um())
        self.current = 'TelaUm'

class Um(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Um, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'TelaUm'
        self.add_widget(UmC())

class UmC(FloatLayout):


    def __init__(self):
        super(UmC, self).__init__()        

        self.btnSelecionado = 'qualquer_merda'

        self.btn = Button(id = 'Bosta!', text = 'Bosta!', pos_hint = { 'center_x' : .5, 'center_y' : .5 }, size_hint = (None, None))
        self.btn.bind(on_press = self.vai)

        self.add_widget(self.btn)

    def vai(self, instance):
        self.parent.parent.add_widget(Dois())
        self.parent.parent.current = 'TelaDois'
        self.btnSelecionado = instance.id

class Dois(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dois, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'TelaDois'
        self.add_widget(DoisC())

class DoisC(UmC, FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DoisC, self).__init__()

        self.btn2 = Button(text = self.btnSelecionado, pos_hint = { 'center_x' : .5, 'center_y' : .5 }, size_hint = (None, None) )
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

Principal().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do. But it looks to me like the second screen is a new instance of `UmC` and therefore has its own value of `btnSelecionado`.  So inevitably this new instance has the value from init since it's only the old instance that has been changed.

```
def vai(self, instance):
    self.parent.parent.add_widget(Dois())
    self.parent.parent.current = 'TelaDois'
    self.btnSelecionado = instance.id
```

Line 2 creates a new instance and line 4 sets the value in the old instance.